the kubernetes promtail did not send logs to loki service
I have deploy the loki service and using this command to check the service deploy:
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -s -X POST "http://139.14.166.24:3100/loki/api/v1/push" \
  --data-raw '{"streams": [{ "stream": { "foo": "bar2" }, "values": [ [ "1732889861000000000", "fizzbuzz" ] ] }]}'

this test log message success write to loki and I can query this log from grafana UI. Then I deploy the promtail into the kubernetes cluster as a DeamonSet like this:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: promtail-daemonset
  namespace: default
  uid: a7801cf9-3f88-4c36-b6a7-0f523db14476
  resourceVersion: '23958317'
  generation: 9
  creationTimestamp: '2024-11-26T13:11:46Z'
  labels:
    k8slens-edit-resource-version: v1
status:
  currentNumberScheduled: 1
  numberMisscheduled: 0
  desiredNumberScheduled: 1
  numberReady: 1
  observedGeneration: 9
  updatedNumberScheduled: 1
  numberAvailable: 1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: promtail
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        name: promtail
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2024-11-30T02:54:09Z'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: logs
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
            type: ''
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
            type: ''
        - name: promtail-config
          configMap:
            name: promtail-config
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
        - name: promtail-container
          image: registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-public/promtail:3.2.0
          args:
            - '-config.file=/etc/promtail/promtail.yaml'
          env:
            - name: iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: logs
              mountPath: /var/log
            - name: promtail-config
              mountPath: /etc/promtail
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: promtail-serviceaccount
      serviceAccount: promtail-serviceaccount
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10

the promtail promtail:3.2.0 config map look like this:
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

clients:
  - url: http://139.14.166.24:3100/loki/api/v1/push

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: kubernetes-pods
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
    pipeline_stages:
      - json:
          expressions:
            level: level
            msg: message
            time: time
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app]
        target_label: app
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
        target_label: namespace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
        target_label: pod_name

but I did not see any log from grafana UI, the promtail did not show any error. Am I missing something? I also tried to add annotation label in the kubernetes deployment like this:
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: texhub-server-service
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: texhub-server-service
      annotations:
        promtail.io/scrape: "true"
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2024-11-06T20:40:11+08:00'
    spec:

still did not found any log, why the promtail did not send the log? This is the promtail pod log output:
level=info ts=2024-11-30T02:54:12.166837213Z caller=promtail.go:133 msg="Reloading configuration file" md5sum=005fc05e10167b7cd219ce7e04437ced
level=info ts=2024-11-30T02:54:12.167927624Z caller=kubernetes.go:331 component=discovery discovery=kubernetes config=kubernetes-pods msg="Using pod service account via in-cluster config"
level=info ts=2024-11-30T02:54:12.170280481Z caller=server.go:351 msg="server listening on addresses" http=[::]:9080 grpc=[::]:33481
level=info ts=2024-11-30T02:54:12.171272194Z caller=main.go:173 msg="Starting Promtail" version="(version=k218-659f542, branch=k218, revision=659f5421)"
level=warn ts=2024-11-30T02:54:12.171339922Z caller=promtail.go:263 msg="enable watchConfig"

this is the hostname look like:
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ ~]# hostname
iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ

I also tried to run the test command in the kubernetes pod using curl, and the log could success send to loki service.

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/grafana/promtail
Try this helm chart, this uses kubernetes service discovery and it is easier to collect logs from all the pods running in the cluster.
If you want to exclude some namespaces updated the values files accordingly.
config:
  snippets:
    extraRelabelConfigs:
      - source_labels: 
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        action: drop
        regex: kube-node-lease|kube-public|kube-system

